Simple Interactions with USD/USDZ files
I would like to make a very simple interaction within a USD/USDZ file that can be viewed on iOS or on macOS (using the quicklook on either device).
I would like to do it programatically (without the use of the GUI tools) is it possible to do so with a set of simple commands in python? Like following this tutorial:
https://openusd.org/release/tut_xforms.html
and adding an action upon click/tap to change the states of the assets?
I have tried to find information on this, but I'm stuck. Is there a way to so (or even directly editing the usda file would do the trick).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
